# Scrapy - Issue with setting FILES_STORE?

Tags: scrapy

So I have a custom pipeline that extends Scrapy's current [FilesPipeline](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/media-pipeline.html#using-the-files-pipeline). However, I'm having trouble with setting the [FILES_STORE](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/media-pipeline.html#enabling-your-media-pipeline) variable. My current file structure is:

```
my_scraper.py 
files/ 
     #this is where I want the files to download to
```

so, I set `FILES_STORE=/files/` and run the spider. But when I do that I get the following error:

> PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/files/'

Why does this happen? Is there anything that I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it's useful to anyone else, it was simple error - `FILES_STORE` requires the full path, not just the relative path from the folder.

Comment: FYI your original path was absolute as well - In unix a path that starts with slash is considered to be absolute. Relative path should have been `files/` in your case so you might want to try that, though absolute paths should always be used instead of relative ones when possible.

Comment: Good to know, thanks! I also tried it with `files/` since I wasn't sure of the difference, and it did not work